# How to draw a loop in Dia?

Tags: diagram, sequence-diagram, dia

I'm trying to build sequence diagram and I would like to represent **Loop** in my diagram ( something like below pic ) How can i do that in Dia ? Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the answer related to Dia, but I suggest you to use DRAKON and particularly DRAKON Editor for making diagrams. DRAKON supports loops and many more. It can also generates code from diagrams. It supports visual programming in several programming languages, including Java, Processing.org, D, C#, C/C++ (with Qt support), Python, Tcl, Javascript, Lua and Erlang. Why to use DRAKON than other diagramming systems?

- No line intersections. You will never find in DRAKON diagram two or
  more lines intersecting each other! Not seen in other diagramming
  systems!
- Silhouette structure. It allows to break one diagram in to several
  logical parts. Not seen in other diagramming systems!
- No slanting or curved lines. Only straight lines with right angles.
- Icons are placed only on vertical lines.
- Branching is done in a simple, visible and consistent way.
- Each diagram has one entry and one exit.

DRAKON Editor homepage http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/

More about DRAKON here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON